# Guidelines on feature development

Tags: team-management

Are there any sources out there on a guidelines how to implement a new feature for web or mobile app from start to finish? I'm looking for how the idea is presented to the team and how the managers, designers, and developers should work together. Specifically in smaller teams, say around 5. Something along the lines of when to involve specific members of the team to understand the problem or new feature required, brainstorming, initial designs and potential solutions, and implementation.

Comment: Like, um, Scrum? :)

Comment: From the question, it sounds more like @ono wants a flow from ideation to actual implementation, not a pure process framework? For instance, Scrum itself would not guide understanding the problem, approach to design (such as set-based), etc.

Comment: Jeff I do think Scrum facilitates that, what do you think the product owner and the planning meetings are for? Maybe it does not give you a clear step-by-step tutorial, but that is because there is not a single way to execute things. If you follow the Scrum format you will notice where you are lacking and then you can address that as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scrum**

Like CodeGnome said have a look at Scrum. Having worked in multiple different teams using Scrum I can totally say this is a good idea.

I just finished [Jeff Sutherlands](http://www.scruminc.com/) latest book [Scrum The Art of Doing Twice The Work In Half the Time](http://www.scruminc.com/new-scrum-the-book/) and I think its a nice read. Giving good practical insights why Scrum works and how to sell it :).

Also have a look at the Scrum getting started guide at: http://www.scrumguides.org/ , but maybe even better try to attend a course and get some handson experience: http://courses.scrum.org/

Read this free eBook over how Scrum could be implemented in a real world example: http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/scrum-xp-from-the-trenches-2